# Python use sorted to sort list of dictionary

Tags: python, sorting

How can i sort a dictionary's inside a dictionary , as the following data :

```
{
  u'attendance': [
    {
      u'1': {
        u'name': u'B',
        u'total_wh': u'09:13:00',
        u'brk_flag': False,
        u'date': u'2016-01-26',
        u'wh_flag': True,
        u'total_brk': u'00:02:00',
        u'uid': 0
      },
      u'0': {
        u'name': u'B',
        u'total_wh': u'10:08:00',
        u'brk_flag': False,
        u'date': u'2016-01-27',
        u'wh_flag': True,
        u'total_brk': u'02:47:00',
        u'uid': 0
      },
      u'2': {
        u'name': u'B',
        u'total_wh': u'07:36:00',
        u'brk_flag': False,
        u'date': u'2016-01-25',
        u'wh_flag': False,
        u'total_brk': u'00:10:00',
        u'uid': 0
      }
    },
    {
      u'0': {
        u'name': u'F',
        u'total_wh': u'06:04:00',
        u'brk_flag': True,
        u'date': u'2016-01-26',
        u'wh_flag': True,
        u'total_brk': u'00:18:00',
        u'uid': 54
      }
    },
    {
      u'1': {
        u'name': u'C',
        u'total_wh': u'07:24:00',
        u'brk_flag': False,
        u'date': u'2016-01-26',
        u'wh_flag': False,
        u'total_brk': u'',
        u'uid': 2000
      },
      u'0': {
        u'name': u'C',
        u'total_wh': u'10:01:00',
        u'brk_flag': False,
        u'date': u'2016-01-27',
        u'wh_flag': True,
        u'total_brk': u'',
        u'uid': 2000
      }
    },
    {
      u'1': {
        u'name': u'A',
        u'total_wh': u'04:05:00',
        u'brk_flag': True,
        u'date': u'2016-01-26',
        u'wh_flag': True,
        u'total_brk': u'00:05:00',
        u'uid': 11014
      },
      u'0': {
        u'name': u'A',
        u'total_wh': u'07:54:00',
        u'brk_flag': False,
        u'date': u'2016-01-27',
        u'wh_flag': True,
        u'total_brk': u'00:10:00',
        u'uid': 11014
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

i was thinking to walk through the list , take each dictionary individually and sort it by date as example  :

```
  [sorted(x.items(),key=lambda x: x[1]['date']) for x in d['attendance']]
```

but still i need to do sorting for all dictionary combined together , lets say i want do sorting by name ... ?  what is the best way doing that

**example of sorting by name  :**

```
   {
      u'attendance': [
 {
          u'1': {
            u'name': u'A',
            u'total_wh': u'04:05:00',
            u'brk_flag': True,
            u'date': u'2016-01-26',
            u'wh_flag': True,
            u'total_brk': u'00:05:00',
            u'uid': 11014
          },
          u'0': {
            u'name': u'A',
            u'total_wh': u'07:54:00',
            u'brk_flag': False,
            u'date': u'2016-01-27',
            u'wh_flag': True,
            u'total_brk': u'00:10:00',
            u'uid': 11014
          }
        },
        {
          u'1': {
            u'name': u'B',
            u'total_wh': u'09:13:00',
            u'brk_flag': False,
            u'date': u'2016-01-26',
            u'wh_flag': True,
            u'total_brk': u'00:02:00',
            u'uid': 0
          },
          u'0': {
            u'name': u'B',
            u'total_wh': u'10:08:00',
            u'brk_flag': False,
            u'date': u'2016-01-27',
            u'wh_flag': True,
            u'total_brk': u'02:47:00',
            u'uid': 0
          },
          u'2': {
            u'name': u'B',
            u'total_wh': u'07:36:00',
            u'brk_flag': False,
            u'date': u'2016-01-25',
            u'wh_flag': False,
            u'total_brk': u'00:10:00',
            u'uid': 0
          }
        },
        {
          u'1': {
            u'name': u'C',
            u'total_wh': u'07:24:00',
            u'brk_flag': False,
            u'date': u'2016-01-26',
            u'wh_flag': False,
            u'total_brk': u'',
            u'uid': 2000
          },
          u'0': {
            u'name': u'C',
            u'total_wh': u'10:01:00',
            u'brk_flag': False,
            u'date': u'2016-01-27',
            u'wh_flag': True,
            u'total_brk': u'',
            u'uid': 2000
          }
        },
{
          u'0': {
            u'name': u'F',
            u'total_wh': u'06:04:00',
            u'brk_flag': True,
            u'date': u'2016-01-26',
            u'wh_flag': True,
            u'total_brk': u'00:18:00',
            u'uid': 54
          }
        }

      ]
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dictionary does not care of sorting.

Comment: please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is too hard to read to answer easily. Read the link Pynchia posted. It is also unclear what "x" is in your question in the sorted code. Do you want to sort the list called "attendance" based on values of the dictionaries contained within it? As Slslam said, dictionaries can't be sorted, but by calling .items() on it as you do, you turn it into a list of tuples and lists can be sorted. So please edit and clarify your question so we can help.

Comment: [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) are unsorted, but you can do the same you did with an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).